# Django createsuperuser error in console

Tags: django

I start new project with two app (**customuser** and **client**). In **customuser** I redefine default User model and in **client** make UserProfile with OneToOne field to User. Then I run

```
makemigartions customuser
makemigrations client
migrate
```

In this point all Ok 
Bun then I run

```
createsuperuser
```

The error is appear

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: client_profile.position_id
```

**customuser/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

**client/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from customuser.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)   

class Position(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=40)   


class Role(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50)      

class Company(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)   

class Profile(models.Model):
    P = 'partner'
    U = 'user'
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (P, 'partner'),
        (U, 'user'),

    )         
    user = models.**OneToOneField**(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES,  default="U")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default = None)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/profile/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.ForeignKey('Position',blank=True, default=None)
    role = models.ForeignKey('Role', blank=True, default=None)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company',blank=True, default=None)
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status',  blank=True, default=None) 


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Help to understand why this is happening and solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because you are creating a user without setting `position`. If you allow null in the database, you need to set `null=True`.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    position = models.ForeignKey('Position',blank=True, null=True)
```

Once you've done this, you'll need to create a migration and migrate to drop the NOT NULL constraint in your database.

Comment: And for all other positions such as role, company, status too?

Comment: I delate my DB and all migrations and make new migratons with new fields configurations from you example, but old error occurred.

Comment: Yes, you may need to add `null=True` for other fields as well, depending on the field type. You don’t need `null=True` for `CharField`s because you can store the empty string `''` if it isn’t specified.